# Javascript form.submit conflicting name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the javascript .submit() to auto submit a form, however one of the fields has a name called submit so it returns.

```
TypeError: document.forms.go.submit is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

document.forms["go"].submit();
```

Is there anything I can use apart from .submit

Comment: I would suggest renaming your `submit` field, but I guess you already thought of that, right?

Comment: I would call it a dupe, but OP, are you ok with renaming the input field? I don't think you'd have many other options anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to **use a name that doesn't cause a conflict**.

You may, however, be able to invoke `submit` via the *prototype*. For example,

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call( // invoke form submit on
    document.forms["go"] // your form
);
```

Similarly you could try to "borrow" it from another `<form>`

```
document.createElement('form').submit.call( // invoke submit from another form on
    document.forms["go"] // your form
);
```

These are more hacks than real solutions, so you should really consider choosing a different name.

Comment: Browsers are not required to implement any kind of inheritance, much less prototype inheritance so I would not suggest attempting to use this approach.

Comment: @RobG true, but that doesn't mean it's never available. Added a second "hack" which does a similar thing. I made it even stronger that removing the name conflict is the better choice, too, in case it wasn't strong enough before.

Comment: That's no better, host objects don't have to implement call, though I'm surprised that IE 8 seems to. :-)